# Python - how to "rerandomize" variables?

Tags: python, blackjack

I'm making a game of blackjack, and I'm wondering how to have random variables come again and again. Also, how to reset a list back to it's original form after taking variables out of it.

So, here's what I have on a smaller basis:

```
card1 = random.randint(0, 3)
deck_of_cards = [A_hearts, 2_diamonds, Queen_hearts, 5_spades]
value = [11, 2, 10, 5]
def dealcards():
     print deck_of_cards[card1]
     print value[card1]
     print 'This is your first card and it's value.'
```

It's very small scale, considering I'm using a whole deck in the real game. 
What I'm asking, is how can I get this to call an ace of hearts one time and a 2 of diamonds the next time I run it.

If you also know, how might I be able to reset a list after I've taken values out of it using del or list.pop?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but general advice: take the time to get familiar with all of the methods available in the `random` module, not just `randint`. In particular I think `shuffle`, `choice`, and `sample` are useful for card games. And if you're thinking "but methods that take elements from a single sequence aren't useful to me because I need to take elements from the two sequences `deck_of_cards` and `value` in parallel", think about how you might condense those two lists into a single list.

Comment: I was actually just thinking about condensing them to one single list, by using lists within lists. I'll have time to work on it in about 20 minutes and I should be able to take some time to experiment. I'll also use that time to familiarize myself with those methods.

Comment: Don't use a list, use a dictionary, cards and their values can be thought of as keys and values.

Comment: _how to reset a list back to it's original form_ Redo whatever you did to make the list in the first place.

Comment: So, do you mean when I after I delete that index in the list, put it back in when I need to reset the deck?

Comment: Well it's possibly a bit more complicated than you have made out here. Normally there would be multiple decks of cards in play in Blackjack. Do you need that kind of functionality in your game?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. My teacher was pretty vague and didn't really help us too much. If everyone else is struggling about to the point that I am, I'm hoping he will be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

The only way to "rerandomize" variables is by using random.randint() again.

I don't know if you can 'reset' a list but by giving the lists as parameters to a function you can keep your orignal lists unharmed.

Hope this helps you.

```
import random

deck_of_cards_original = ["A_hearts", "2_diamonds", "Queen_hearts", "5_spades"]
value_original = [11, 2, 10, 5]


playerCardsNames = []
playerCardsValues = []

def dealcards(deck_of_cards, value): #give lists as parameters so you can keep the original card list

   card1 = random.randint(0, 3)    #all cards still avaiable so randint(0, 3)
   print(deck_of_cards[card1])
   print(value[card1])
   print('''This is your first card and it's value.''')
   playerCardsNames.append(value[card1])   #saves the card names and values of the players in a new list
   playerCardsValues.append(value[card1])  #
   del deck_of_cards[card1]    #the card is out of the deck now so delete it
   del value[card1]

   print("")

   card2 = random.randint(0, 2)    #randint with one card less because the player has it now
   print(deck_of_cards[card2])
   print(value[card2])
   print('''This is your second card and it's value.''')
   playerCardsNames.append(value[card2])   #same thing as before
   playerCardsValues.append(value[card2])
   del deck_of_cards[card2]
   del value[card2]


dealcards(deck_of_cards_original, value_original)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this properly in terms of Blackjack would take something more involved than the code below because you would generally have multiple decks of cards in play. You'd also probably want a generator to `yield` the cards rather than working with a whole pre-determined deck.

However, it *illustrates* how you can randomise a deck of cards and exhaust it one-by-one, whilst using a dictionary to also hold the card values. To create a fresh deck, just call `create_fresh_deck()` again.

```
import random
import time

def create_fresh_deck():
    suits = [' of Hearts', ' of Diamonds', ' of Spades', ' of Clubs']

    # Below uses "list concatenation"
    cards = ['Ace'] + list(map(str, range(2, 11))) + ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    values = list(range(1, 11)) + [10, 10, 10]

    # Dictionary comprehension to knit them together
    deck = {cards[x] + suits[y]: values[x] 
            for y, _ in enumerate(suits) for x, _ in enumerate(cards)}

    return deck

deck = create_fresh_deck()
deck_cards = list(deck.keys())
random.shuffle(deck_cards) # randomise your deck in place

for card in deck_cards:
    if 'ace' not in card.lower():
        print("The card is {} with value {}".format(card, deck[card]))
    else:
        print("The card is {} with value 1 or 11".format(card))
    time.sleep(0.5) # Just to slow down the print outputs a bit
```